# How to disable SQLAlchemy query cache?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pytest, python-asyncio

I'm new to both async and SQLAlchemy.  I'm trying to setup the infrastructure for my test suite.  I've created a session fixture based on doc section [Joining a Session into an External Transaction](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites)

```
@pytest.fixture( name="s", scope="function" )
async def fixture_s():
    connection  = await DB.engine.connect()
    transaction = await connection.begin()
    session     = Session( bind=connection )
    yield session
    session.close()
    await transaction.rollback()
    await connection.close()
```

Also the Model class:

```
class Thingy( Model ):
    __tablename__ = "thingies"
    id   : Mapped[ int ] = mapped_column( primary_key=True )
    name : Mapped[ str ] = mapped_column( String( 50 )     )

    @classmethod
    async def count( cls ):
        async with DB.Session() as s:
            res = await s.scalar( select( func.count( cls.id ) ) )
        return res
```

If I run the following test:

```
async def test__foo( self, s ):
    assert 0 == await Thingy.count()
```

It passes.  If I run the following test:

```
async def test__foo( self, s ):
    s.add( Thingy( name="foo" ) )
    assert 1 == await Thingy.count()
```

That passes.  However, if I combine them:

```
async def test__foo( self, s ):
    assert 0 == await Thingy.count()
    s.add( Thingy( name="foo" ) )
    assert 1 == await Thingy.count()
```

It fails because the second query returns the same result (0).

```
------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:2685 BEGIN (implicit)
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1844 SELECT count(thingies.id) AS count_1 
FROM thingies
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1844 [generated in 0.00016s] ()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:2688 ROLLBACK
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:2685 BEGIN (implicit)
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1844 SELECT count(thingies.id) AS count_1 
FROM thingies
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1844 [cached since 0.004266s ago] ()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:2688 ROLLBACK
```

From the part that says "cached since 0.004266s ago" I deduce that it cached the first count query and gave me the cached result the second time.

How do I make it not do that?

Comment: The `[cached since...` messages refer to the caching of _statements_, not results.

Comment: If you want to disable query caching, see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#disabling-or-using-an-alternate-dictionary-to-cache-some-or-all-statements

Comment: UPDATE:  I gave up on async and started over with normal SQLAlchemy + pytest and eventually ended up with a completely different test harness solution.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLAlchemy, the caching of the results of the SQL statement occurs within the scope of the session. The second time you're calling `Thingy.count()`, it's creating a new session, hence the cached result.

The solution here would be to commit the session after adding the `Thingy` object. SQLAlchemy will flush the pending changes to the database when the transaction is committed. This means that the changes are now visible to other transactions, and any subsequent SELECT within the same transaction will retrieve the updated data.

You can modify your test function as follows:

```py
async def test__foo( self, s ):
    assert 0 == await Thingy.count()
    s.add( Thingy( name="foo" ) )
    await s.commit()   # Commit the session after adding the Thingy object
    assert 1 == await Thingy.count()
```

Keep in mind that by using `await s.commit()`, you're making a commit to the database which is not generally recommended in tests as it can interfere with database state across tests. To avoid this, you can use savepoints.

```py
async def test__foo( self, s ):
    assert 0 == await Thingy.count()
    s.add( Thingy( name="foo" ) )
    await s.flush()   # Flush the session, this will not commit the transaction, but will send the INSERT to the database
    assert 1 == await Thingy.count()
    await s.rollback()  # Rollback any changes made during the test
```

In this version of the test, `s.flush()` is used instead of `s.commit()`. This will send the INSERT statement to the database, but it will not commit the transaction. Then, the `s.rollback()` at the end of the test will rollback any changes made during the test.

Also, please ensure that your tests are running in isolation and that the database is properly cleaned up between test runs to avoid any interference from previous tests.

Comment: I tried it, and the line `await s.flush()` generated:  AttributeError: 'AsyncConnection' object has no attribute 'connect'